# No puedo mostrar la variable en mi consola con la sentencia switch en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda, sé que esta pregunta es muy básica, pues estoy iniciando en el mundo de la programación, ya busqué en todos lados en internet pero no encuentro una respuesta. Estoy intentando mostrar la variable "total" en la consola y no puedo. Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

ESTE ES EL CóDIGO:

```js
var minutos = 102;
var total = 0;

switch (minutos) {
    case (minutos <= 100):
        total = (minutos * 0.45);
        console.log(total);
        break;
    case (minutos <= 200):
        total = (minutos * 0.40);
        console.log(total);
        break;
    case (minutos <= 400):
        total = (minutos * 0.45) - 5.00;
        console.log(total);
        break;
    case (minutos > 400):
        total = (minutos * 0.45) - 10.00;
        console.log(total);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Debes usar las sentencias if,  else if y else para ello,  el switch no sirve para ese proposito,  considera que switch NO se usa para comprobar condiciones si no mas bien para comparar el valor de una variable con otros.

Comment: Es decir que en switch no deberias tener condicionales. La idea del switch es tener valores inmediatos.

Comment: Para usar `switch` el valor del `case` debe ser estático  es decir un valor que se identico, por ejemplo case 100 o case 150, para tu caso es mejor usar `if` con `elseif`

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos! Fueron de mucha ayuda! Bendiciones!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido a la comunidad, Steven.
Los switch en la mayoria de los lenguajes funciona de la siguiente manera:

```
a = 1
switch (a) {
    case 1:
        alert('case 1 executed');
        break;
    case 2:
        alert("case 2 executed");
        break;
   case 3:
        alert("case 3 executed");
        break;
    case 4:
        alert("case 4 executed");
        break;
    default:
        alert("default case executed");
}
```

Posiblemente piensas que la maquina va buscar y evaluar el caso para entrar en el apropiado, lo cual no es correcto. Es decir, tu estas intentando algo parecido a:

```
a = false; // 0 == false == "" == {}
switch (a) {
    case false:
        alert('case false executed');
        break;
    case true:
        alert("case true executed");
        break;
   case true:
        alert("never!");
        break;
    case true:
        alert("never!");
        break;
    default:
        alert("never!");
}
```

Hay varias opciones para resolver tu problema:

**Solucion 1: if**

```js
 function getTotal(minutos) {
    if (minutos <= 100){
        return (minutos * 0.45);}
    if (minutos <= 200){
        return (minutos * 0.40);}
    if (minutos <= 400){
        return (minutos * 0.45) - 5.00;}
    return (minutos * 0.45) - 10.00;
}
console.log(getTotal(102));
```

Otras opciones son mas complejas, pero escalables (es decir, si manana tienes un millon de condicionles):

1. Algoritmo optimizados. Crear una regla aritmetica superior a partir de un patron.
2. Patron de diseno. Un conjunto de clases y polimorfismo.
3. Guardar en una base de datos (ya sea en el browser o externo) las reglas de negocio.

Por cierto, aprende ingles y escribe tu codigo en ingles, son el estandar.

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias en serio que ya le entendi a mi problema,en serio aprecio mucho el tiempo que se tomó para ayudarme realmente. Espero que tenga un grandioso dia, espero que este muy bien. Bendiciones! Y Bienvenido a la comunidad tambíen, parece que ambos somos nuevos.!!